# BSOD Unexpected Kernel Mode Trap minidump

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bsod

Updated recently to Windows 1809 (right when it came out, actually. Foolish of me, since the next day I started hearing about lots of people losing their data from this update. Thankfully I still have my data, but I HAVE started getting Unexpected Kernel Mode Trap BSODs fairly often. Computer restarts too quickly for me to write down the error codes, but there are several. I believe the first two started with FFFA... and FFF8... but I don't remember the rest of either code, or what the other ones started with (but there were like four or five error codes all listed in the corner of the screen).

Can't figure out what's triggering the BSODs, but it seems to happen at some point after I've launched MS Word (which is a problem, as I'm a writer), and seems to happen mostly after the pc has been woken up from sleep mode. I read online that it could be a driver problem, but all my drivers are up-to-date, or a RAM problem, but I ran mdsched.exe (extended) and it turned up no errors.

Here's the [Minidump](https://www.mediafire.com/file/y2cmcjqpwchyki7/101118-11453-01.dmp/file) for the most recent BSOD. Could someone please analyze it and tell me what you think the most likely culprit and fix is?

Thanks a million!

(Running Windows 10 Home 1809, build 17763.1, on Asus Q302LA, SMBIOS version 2.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the system crashed with a kernel stack overflow due to a driver called 0patchDriver64.sys. Did you install an antimalware thing called "0patch"? I'd remove it. If this just started after the 1809 update, then I would say 0patch is not compatible with that update.

Answer (score 0):

Mitja Kolsek of 0patch here. First: aargh, we hate that we're causing you problems. We've had one case of BSOD reported before and gave the affected user an updated Agent that resolved the problem. We'd appreciate you contacting us on support@0patch.com so we can provide you with a new Agent build that will likely resolve this problem for you too. It's currently an internal build but will, if it passes the tests, become official in a few days. Thank you in advance!

Mitja

Comment: I donno about the downvotes and the flags. Based off Jamie's answer, their product caused the crash and they want to make it right

Comment: Thank you Mitja! I love your program and I'm glad you're on top of fixing the driver issue. I marked Jamie's answer as correct, as it was the one to diagnose the issue, but I upvoted your comment for being the one to fix it. I don't know who's downvoting you :(

Comment: ftr, I gave Mitja no downvotes and no flags :)